# error in closing autoform template

Tags: meteor

I have this piece of code in my meteor application.
Meteor version is : Meteor 1.0.3.1

The code well formatted as required by blaze template. But I don't understand this problem.

I was able to use quickForm of autoform package but not able to use autoform.

```html
<template name="register">
{{> autoForm collection="Users" id="addUserForm" type="insert"}}
<fieldset>
  <legend>Register</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      {{> afFieldInput name="firstName" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName"}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputLastName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPass" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPass" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputMobileNum" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Mobile Number</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="inputMobileNum" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputDOB" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputDOB" placeholder="Date of Birth" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="bgroup" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Blood Group</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="bgroup">
        <option>A+</option>
        <option>A-</option>
        <option>B+</option>
        <option>B-</option>
        <option>AB+</option>
        <option>AB-</option>
        <option>O+</option>
        <option>O-</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="country" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Country</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="country">
        <option>India</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="state" class="col-lg-2 control-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="state">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city" class="col-lg-2 control-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="city">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
  </div>
</div>
{{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

I am getting following error:

```
 While building the application:
 register.html:96: Unexpected closing template tag
 ... </div> {{/autoForm}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Spacebars syntax](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md).

`{{> template ... }}` means, put the contents of "template" there. There's no closing tag; it's just a one-line inclusion.

`{{# block ... }}` on the other hand, is a block helper, which has content and a matching closing tag `{{/block}}`. The most popular block helper is `each`:

```
{{#each players}}
  {{> player}}
{{/each}}
```

So you don't need `{{/autoform}}`.

Comment: {{/autoform}} is required for inserting closing form tag. otherwise output would be <form></form><input ......>

Comment: sorry. There was type in my code. You were right. It should have been {{# autoForm}}